# Resize width tabs jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs

Hi im doing a application on asp.net MVC 5.
But i have a problem can someone tell me please how to resize the width of jquery tabs to the content.
My code for now is this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
  });


</script>

 <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Publicar Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Partilhar Ficheiro</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            @ViewBag.item
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Criar_Post", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
            @Html.TextArea("Post", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("post")
            @Html.DropDownList("Privacidade", (SelectList)ViewBag.Privacidade, "---Privacidade---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("privacidade")
            <input type="submit" value="Criar">
            }
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Partilhar_Ficheiro", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
            <label name="nome"></label>
            <input type="file" name="nome" />
            <input type="submit" value="Inserir" class="btn btn-default" />

            }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the height / width of the tabs to the document height / width.

Set the height after initializing the tabs.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
    //Set Height
        $('#tabs').tabs().height($(document).height());
  });
</script>
```